# Retrieving value from html select

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, html-select

I'm using an html select tag to have a list of values from my data base (column name is "DB"), in the page load - the list is populated with the right values but after the user selects a value from the list and clicks a button, when I'm trying to retrieve this value - I always get the value of the first item in the list regardless of user's selection.

aspx code:

```
<select id="id1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></select>
<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

c# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InstanceData = (DataSet)(Session["InstanceData"]);
    id1.DataSource = InstanceData.tables[0];
    id1.DataTextField = "DB";
    id1.DataValueField = "DB";
    id1.DataBind();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string DataBase = id1.Value;
}
```

Comment: [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx) will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will help you

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!IsPostBack)
        {
         InstanceData = (DataSet)(Session["InstanceData"]);
         id1.DataSource = InstanceData.tables[0];
         id1.DataTextField = "DB";
         id1.DataValueField = "DB";
         id1.DataBind();
        }
    }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string DataBase = id1.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the value on the `SelectedIndexChanged` event if you are using dropdown list.